# Can't display notifications with Quasar Notify plugin

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

When using Quasar [Notify plugin](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify) under some unknown circumstances, you may get the following error after calling Notify.create:

*TypeError: quasar_1.Notify.create is not a function"*

Even if Notify is listed under framework.plugins array in quasar.conf.js.

As stated in the docs, you should  `import {Notify} from 'quasar'` when using it outside of .vue files and

```
$q = useQuasar();
$q.notify(...)
```

Inside of vue components.

Answer (score 1):

As described on [this issue](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/7206), although the issue is related to vite-plugin instead of quasar webpack app and Notify being used in another context, it appears to be some issue when three shaking the import list.

If imported using the actual path of the plugin, it works fine.

`import Notify from 'quasar/src/plugins/Notify'`

It will loose TypesScript reference though.